# Whats faster for syncing remote to local filesystem, SSH or FTP?

Tags: ssh, sync, ftp

We have a cloud server with a large file directory which needs to be synchronized with a local system.

Which would be quicker and more reliable for such a task, SSH or FTP. FTP seems to drop the connection and even truncate files at its own will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no information about speed, but ssh/sftp is likely to be more reliable than FTP, and certainly more secure.

However, in this case I would recommend [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). It uses delta compression for fast transfers, and is designed expressly for synchronizing files.

Comment: +1 - rsync is the way to go for something like this.